# Get output of method from another class and test it in unittest

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unittest

I am creating a unittest and I want to test the output of a method. My code is kinda big so I will use a little example. Let's say my method looks like this.

```
def foo():
     print "hello"
```

Now I go to my unittest class and I run the code in the unittest like this.

```
def test_code():
     firstClass.foo()
```

I want to test the output I get from the console. I saw some people using `subprocess` but there I can only give arguments. So my question is how could I get the output from the console to test it in my unittest class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to [remap stdout to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python) and process the file post execution of your method inside your unit test class.

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open('result', 'w')

test_code()
# read 'result'
```

**Edit:** Alternatively, you could manipulate the file stream using the `StringIO` module.

```
import StringIO
output = StringIO.StringIO()
sys.stdout = output
```

Example:

```
#!remap.py
import sys
import StringIO

backup_sys = sys.stdout # backup our standard out
output = StringIO.StringIO() # creates file stream for monitoring test result
sys.stdout = output
print 'test' # prints to our IO stream

sys.stdout = backup_sys # remap back to console
print output.getvalue() # prints the entire contents of the IO stream
```

Output

```
test
```

[More details on the module can be found here.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html)

Comment: Well that might work but I don't want to create a file, because it's just a test.

Comment: I've added an alternative method that may work for you: the `StringIO module`. This will emulate the file write method and allow you to easily remap the `print` function.